# pytest, initialize webdriver for each test file with teardown quit

Tags: python, testing, webdriver, pytest, fixtures

**Current part of code in the test module:**

```
def test_01():
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

**Conftest code:**

```
import pytest
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait


@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def browser():
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r"C:\webdrivers\1\chromedriver.exe")
    driver.implicitly_wait(5)
    wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
    driver.maximize_window()
    yield
    driver.quit()
```

**Result**: "E       NameError: name 'driver' is not defined"

**Target result**: initialize webdriver without class, setup webdriver as driver into each test function, run function with it and quit with fixtures postcondition from conftest. I have a lot of test files and thats why I should to do it once.

I've also tried return variable from fixture, but as I understood the test function still need to have variable for fixture and it looks wrong as for me. For example: fixture - return x, testfunction(fixture): x = fixture. And it still not works with webdriver\driver (or rather I didn’t figure it out).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your test function needs to take the fixture as an argument, that's the first part of the problem.

For instance:

```py
def test_01(driver):
    driver.get('https://www.google.com')
```

But you don't have a `driver` fixture yet, just one called `browser`, so you'll need to change the name of the fixture:

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def driver(request):
   ...
```

Finally, the fixture needs to return the driver, so that you can use it.

```py
@pytest.fixture(autouse=True)
def driver(request):
    ...
    yield driver
    ...
```

Comment: Thank you very much mr, it works! Can you clarify - why should i link argument to my test function if I used autouse param? Just to know for me and people with similar tasks.

Comment: I believe that `autouse` ensures the fixture is called before each test, for instance if you want to do some common setup before every test. I think the intention is for it to be used mainly where the fixture doesn't return anything. 

If the fixture does return something then your test needs a way to access the thing that is returned. There a few ways you could do that:
1. Add the result to the global namespace
2. Pass the result as an argument to the test

`1` is messy and I don't believe pytest does this. I think `2` is what happens, so your test needs to define that argument.